# How to complete my first session?

Tags: gm-techniques, campaign-development, artifacts

I'm preparing campaign for my friends. It's first time for all of us and I want to create a big bang at the beginning. My players are a high elf, a wood elf and a tiefling.

They will start in quite a big village, where everything is fine, crops are plenty etc. I need a way to introduce the elves to each other, have a plan for the tiefling and make them do quest or two together.

In the end I want the whole village destroyed by demons, summoned by the magic item they find in the dungeon nearby, but I have no idea how to introduce something that important to my plot in such place. I want it to be a part of bigger artifact used to summon a demon god, which they have to stop in the endgame.

How should I introduce the item? Is it too much for the first session? Thanks for the answers.

Comment: What game (and edition) are you playing and what issues do you see with introducing the artefact?

Comment: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/39544/what-to-do-in-the-first-session-of-a-campaign?rq=1 this question has a lot of tips that should be applicable to many different RPGs! It's less focused on introducing an item specifically, but I think a lot of the advice is helpful anyway.